# Why is node -v command not working with wsl2 Ubuntu 20.04 on windows

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I installed Ubuntu 20.04 on my windows 11 system but i can't run the **"node -v"** command like i used to with my powershell cmd.

It is saying command node not found, but I can run the same command on cmd and have the node version installed on my system display.

Please any solution

Comment: The node installed for your Windows OS won't run under Linux. Did you install node for Linux?

Comment: How do i do that

Comment: @HillaRion Apologies if I am misunderstanding, but it sounds like your question is just "How do I install Node for Linux?"  If so, I would encourage you to start by reading the Stack, "[How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)", starting with "Search, and research".  Have you *searched* for information on how to install Node on Linux?  What did you find?  Why didn't that work for you?

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds I am running wsl2 on my windows laptop but the "node -v" and other node related command are not working when i start the bash shell(with ubuntu 20.04) but the same command works with my window cmd, now I want to know if i will need to install node for the wsl2 or if there is a way for me to use the one install directly on my system through my windows cmd

Comment: As I said in my answer (which I deleted, since it didn't seem to be what you were looking for; now un-deleted), you *can* run the Windows node, but it isn't recommend.  As mentioned above in the comments, you should install the Linux Node in WSL, but then you asked "How do I do that."

Answer (score 1):

Some of the comments mention this briefly, but I think it warrants a more detailed explanation, with some additional information to help you on your WSL journey.

First, WSL *does* allow you to run Windows executables, but it requires the full executable name -- For instance, `node.exe`, assuming it is in your path.  Otherwise, it would need `/mnt/c/path/to/node.exe`.

WSL also appends the Windows path to the Windows path, and translates it to the Linux form, so you'll automatically find things like:

- `/mnt/c/Windows`
- `/mnt/c/Windows/System32`
- `/mnt/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0`

...and others in when you `echo $PATH` under WSL/Linux.  This means you can run PowerShell from within WSL/Linux as `powershell.exe`, and can even execute scripts and commands like `powershell.exe -c "Get-Help" | less`.  Hey, finally - A decent pager under PowerShell! ;-)

That said, even if you can run the Windows `node.exe` under WSL, it's a bad idea to do so.  The Windows version of Node understands *Windows* drives, *Windows* paths, and *Windows* network interfaces.  When you are running in WSL, the shell will pass in the *Linux* path to a Windows command.

You can work around this with the `wslpath` command (installed by default in some WSL distributions), but really, as the comments pointed out, if you are running in WSL/Linux, you should install the Linux version of Node.

I recommend picking one or the other until you understand the differences, and unless you have a *need* for the Windows version, I'd recommend the Linux route.

This also means that you should keep your project files in WSL, probably in a directory under your Linux `$HOME` directory (i.e. `/mnt/username`).  With WSL2, at least, this has two advantages:

- Much faster performance (Visual Studio Code will even warn you of the performance penalty if you try to keep them on a Windows drive)
- inotify support for projects where you enabled automatic watching/reload.  This will not work with files on the Windows drive when working under WSL, but will work on the default WSL filesystem.

Comment: I just want to use the "bash" shell that is why i installed the wsl2, when i run node.exe it do works but i don't want that, i need it to b working as it should on a normal cmd